# HTAccess Rewrite based upon a Parameter Value, ignore other Parameters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

another HTAccess rewrite issue, sorry....

I'm trying to rewrite all URL's that have menuid=28421, menuid=27384 and menuid=73841. The issue is that the menuid is part of a longer query string, but not all parameters are present in the query string. I want to rewrite only based on the value of menuid, and ignore the other parameters.

```
http://www.domain.com/shop.php?menuid=28421&menuref=Ja&menutitle=New+Products&limit=5&page=8
http://www.domain.com/shop.php?menuid=27384&menuref=Ic&menutitle=Old+Products&page=3
http://www.domain.com/shop.php?menuid=73841&menuref=Hd&limit=10&page=14
```

Result of redirection:

```
http://www.domain.com/new.html
http://www.domain.com/old.html
http://www.domain.com/sale.html
```

Tried this below, but no dice:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^menuid=28421$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ http://www.domain.com/new.html? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

I automatically generate wegpages based on menuid for my product categories:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^menuid=28421&page=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ http://www.domain.com/new.html? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Suggested addition by @anubhava:

```
## 301 Redirects of Individual Menus, Ignoring the Limit Parameter etc...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)menuid=(?:28421|12356)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ http://www.domain.com/new.html? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Thank you for any advice,

Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a better regex for matching QUERY_STRING in this case.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(menuid=[^&]+).+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=302,NE,NC,L]
```

`menuidid=28421` can appear in QUERY_STRING at any position.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, I tried this but get a 500 Internal Server Error. I'll have a play to try and work out why. Thank you so much for your quick reply, Mark. P.S. should "|73841)(?:&|$" be "|73841)(?:&|$)"? If so I now get, "The page isn't redirecting properly".

Comment: I think it must be because I use menuid to dynamically generate the new.html, old.html sale.html. Can I pass the menuid parameter to the shop\.php$ part of the rewrite so that the PHP can generate the output file based upon the menuid? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my code. Just edited it, can you try now.

Comment: I fixed the lost bracket and it states that, "The page isn't redirecting properly", and I assume its because the RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ needs the menuid appended to it so that the new.html file can be dynamically generated by the PHP. Thank you so much again.

Comment: `?` in the end will strip any query string hence `"The page isn't redirecting properly"` shouldn't come. Can you post your complete & latest .htaccess by editing your question.

Comment: the HTAccess file is huge as the ecommerce website has so many changes over the last 5 years. I shall add the lines that currently generate the new.html webpage.

Comment: ## 301 Redirects of Individual Meus, Ignoring the Limit Parameter etc...
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)menuid=(?:2738421|123456)(?:&|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ http://www.domain.com/new.html? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
Is what I have added and suggested by yourself. This is before my original rewrite to new.html @anubhava.

Comment: Is there any rule OR code adding `?manuid= 28421` query parameter in URI?

Comment: Not in the HTAccess file, only a link from Google that contains all the parameters,that is why I want to rewrite the URL. @anubhava.

Comment: Ok in that case can you test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issue?

Comment: "The page isn't redirecting properly", HTAccess based on the addition suggested by yourself and added to the original question :( @anubhava

Comment: Can you run it in Firebug and see what you get in Net tab?

Comment: But you should be seeing multiple of these right in order to get `"The page isn't redirecting properly"`

Comment: Yes, 21 requests. @anubhava

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40760/discussion-between-anubhava-and-barton)