# Rewrite in HTACCESS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone help me here? I did a rewrite for the english version of my site.

It's was `mysite.com/?lang=en` And now it's `mysite.com/en/`

I've tried redirecting the URL with this :

```
RewriteRule ?lang=en$ /en/ [R=301,L]
```

But each time I put this line in my HTACCESS, the website goes down.

Comment: You need to check your error log as it's probably telling you something important.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule is trying to use the parameter portion of the URL.  There is an existing SO answer with an example:

[HTAccess Rewrite based upon a Parameter Value, ignore other Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833834/htaccess-rewrite-based-upon-a-parameter-value-ignore-other-parameters)

Perhaps something like this will help:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(lang=en+).+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=302,NE,NC,L]
```